# Review scraping form tripadvisor

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, tripadvisor

I am new to web scraping in python3. I want to scrape the reviews of all the hotels in dubai but the problem is I can only scrape the hotel review which I describe in the url. Can anyone show me how I can get all of the hotel reviews without implicitly giving url of each hotel?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


importurl = 'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g295424-d302778-Reviews-Roda_Al_Bustan_Dubai_Airport-Dubai_Emirate_of_Dubai.html'
r = requests.get(importurl)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")
 resultsoup = soup.find_all("p", {"class" : "partial_entry"})
#save the reviews to a test text file locally
for review in resultsoup:
review_list = review.get_text()
print(review_list)
with open('testreview.txt', 'w') as fid: 
    for review in resultsoup:
        review_list = review.get_text()
        fid.write(review_list)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should find the index page of all hotel, get all the link into a list, than loop the url list to get comment.

```
import bs4, requests
index_pages = ('http://www.tripadvisor.cn/Hotels-g295424-oa{}-Dubai_Emirate_of_Dubai-Hotels.html#ACCOM_OVERVIEW'.format(i) for i in range(0, 540, 30))
urls = []
with requests.session() as s:
    for index in index_pages:
        r = s.get(index)
        soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
        url_list = [i.get('href') for i in soup.select('.property_title')]
        urls.append(url_list)
```

out:

```
len(urls): 540
```

Comment: This is not the full list of hotels, but hotels from first page only: there are 18 pages more..

Comment: @Andersson This is a example, if you can get 1 page, just use loop to get 18 page .

Comment: But there is no page numeration for results. `URL` is always `http://www.tripadvisor.cn/Hotels-g295424-Dubai_Emirate_of_Dubai-Hotels.html` no matter which page it is: 1st or 19th...

Comment: @Andersson  yes, I notice that, this page use JavaScript to fetch data, it's hard to use requests to handle that.

Comment: @Andersson  Done!

Comment: Just a little remark about your code: you should use `urls.extend(url_list)` instead of `urls.append(url_list)` as `append()` is for `one_list + value` and `extend()` is for `one_list + another_list`

Comment: ...and one more :) because of some duplicates, final version of `urls` should be: `urls = set(urls)`

Comment: @Andersson thx for point out, and please accept the answer to close this question.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not able to do so, as it isn't my question :)

Comment: @Andersson I assume you are OP.............................................. thanks for your comment.

Comment: @宏杰李 thanku sooo much :) my problem is solved now thankx again

Comment: @Hifza ahmad please accept the answer to close this question.